# How can I turn partially selected areas into fully selected areas in Gimp?

Tags: gimp, transparency, photo-editing, selections, anti-aliasing

In Gimp, I have one large selection that resulted from attaching multiple smaller selections to each other. Unfortunately, some of these selections were mistakenly created with feathering applied, causing slivers of partially selected areas that I want to get rid of now.

I confirmed this by opening the *Selection Editor*, which shows fully selected areas in white, unselected areas in black, and partially selected areas in a shade of grey. Is there any way I can apply a threshold function of sorts to turn all these greys into white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Blunt way:

`Select>Sharpen` (which thresholds at 128)

#### More accurate way:

- Enter ["Quick mask" mode](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-image-window-qmask-button.html)
- Use the Threshold tool (or any paint/color tool, for that matter) to fix the selection.
- Exit quickmask mode

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use a layer mask to temporarily store your selection, so that you can edit it as you would any other image, much like the image you can see in the Selection Editor panel.

- Add a layer mask to a new blank layer.  Choose the option "from
  seletion" when applying the mask. This will store your current
  selection as an image much like the one you can see in the selection
  editor panel.  At this point you can release your selection, since
  it's safely stored in the layer mask.
- Right click the layer mask thumbnail, and choose Show Layer Mask, and
  make sure you click the layer mask thumbnail to select it.
- Now you can apply the threshold filter, or edit the mask by painting
  on it etc.
- After you have edited it, turn it back into a selection by right
  clicking the layer mask thumbnail and choosing Mask to Selection.
- You can hide the layer mask by right clicking and uncheck the Show
  Layer Mask option. And obviously you can delete the layer with the
  mask if you have no need for it.

Comment: Less artificially, you can save the selection to a channel, edit the channel, and set the selection from the result. But this is still way too complicated compared to using the quickmask...

Comment: @xenoid - yes, I forgot about the Quickmask.